# javascript multiple returns in one functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, return, google-cloud-functions

i've been working with firebase cloud functions and i ran into a trouble.

i wanna retrieve data from my firebase realtime database like this

```
function get(){
  return firebase.database().ref('/state').once('value', (snapshot) => {
  return snapshot.val();
  });
}
```

but the proslblem is that when i call get() it immediately returns something like `[object Promise]` because of the `return firebase.database()...`

is there a way how to return only `snapshot.val()` ??

Comment: It returns a promise since it is asynchronous. `get().then(val => console.log(val))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Javascript is asynchronous. Please read about [promises and how it works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).
Your `get()` returns a promise you need to wait for it to resolve using `then`

```
function get(){
    return firebase.database()
    .ref('/state')
    .once('value', 
        (snapshot) => {
            //This is a arrow function and return is for this callback function passed to once
            return snapshot.val();
         });
}
```

You can use use callback function inside `then` to get response from promise.

```
//Passing a callback function inside then which will print snapshot value
get().
then(val => console.log(val))
```

With ES7 you can also use `async await` structure for promises.